# Swift UITableView! How to handle multiple selection?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to select multiple items from the `tableView`! But I don't know how to handling. Because I'm a new to the Swift programming language. I found Apple's sample codes, but it is an Objective C codes! Can anybody help me about multiple selection?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you ever check the attribute inspector? There is choice whether you want single, multiple and no selection.

[image]